# Angular UI route states are not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

so i have been following a tutorial on how to use AngularJS ui route. I manage to get the views working just fine. However in trying to get the states to work and its just not working. I followed the tutorial exactly but for some reason my states to just show up. Hopefully someone can help me out. 
[image]
[image]

Scirpt.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('home.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'views/partial-home-list.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
            }
        })
        .state('home.paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
        })
        .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        })
        .state('/views/about', {
            // Figure out later    
        });

});
```

index.html

```
 <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper" ng-app="routerApp">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Content Page</h1>
                        <p>This is where the template of the vast amount of pages will be loaded. This will keep it a single page applcatino. The 
                           main page will inject the html that needs to be loaded to the user. While the top nav bar will allow the user to 
                           view the rest of the website, which will be separate pages 
                        </p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Angular Template, this is where content will be injected -->
            <div ng-include="pages"></div>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>

    <a ui-sref=".list" class="btn btn-primary">List</a>
    <a ui-sref=".paragraph" class="btn btn-danger">Paragraph</a>

</div>
```

partial-home-list.html

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{ dog }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/cN5uM1m20DHGps8cZgzt

Comment: Can you create fiddle or plunker that with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that shows the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I made a plunker, but nohting is working on the plunker, so i dont think it will be any hlep

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cN5uM1m20DHGps8cZgzt

Comment: Can i just upload files to plunker instead, because atleast the routes are working on my pc

Comment: Never-mind, found some links that got it working. Yeah still cant get the states to work. Hopefully this helps people out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using nested states and views ("home.list" is nested inside "home"), you need to include `<div ui-view></div>` in your home.html as well.

For further information: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views

Good luck! :)

Comment: Crap, that was the first thing i removed, before fixing the links, i took out thinking it was the problem. I Could have saved my self 40 mins trying to fix this problem. Fair enough Thanks for helping me see that.